# Boto3 run_instances: How to specify more than one Subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a VPC-enabled Lambda from which I'm launching an EC2 using the run_instances() API. I have configured VPC, two subnets and a security group in the Lambda allowing for high availability. In run_instances(), I'm allowed to specify only one subnetid. Is there a reason why I can specify only one subnet in run_instances()? My understanding is that by specifying more than one subnet it allows for high availability, any reason this is not available in run_instances()?

Answer (score 1):

Subnet ID is the id of the subnet in which we will be launching the instance into. If you specify a network interface, you can specify any subnets as part of the network interface.

Comment: Thanks. I need to use the Subnet in run_instances() and cannot specifcy network interface. This is because without Subnet run_instances()  would launch the EC2 in the default VPC and I don't want this.